# Probability-Calculating Combined probality of multiple events

Tags: probability

1. The question is: In a production process, three units are selected randomly without replacement from a lot of 100 units for quality control. If all three are found defective then the lot is rejected, otherwise accepted. If a lot contains 15 defective items, find the probability that the lot is (1) Rejected.  (2) Accepted
2. The solution is quite simple -- Prob of lot being rejected is

P(REJECTED)= (15/100)(14/99)(13/98) which works out to 0.00281 and

P(ACCEPTED) = 1-P(REJECTED) =1-.00281 = 0.99719

3. The doubt that comes is ---- Why cant P (ACCEPTED) be calculated as

P(ACCEPTED) = (85/100)(84/99)(83/98)?
 This probability works out to 0.6108. Does it mean that in this calculation some event with probality of (0.99719-.6108=0.3863) is being missed out?

4. I am unable to figure out the anomaly....request help

Comment: OK.  I got it......P(Accpted) will also include cases where 1 of the three is defective and two of the three are defective.... Their probabilities would add to 0.6108 to give 0.99719.      Now I feel sheepish to have asked a silly question that I myself could figure out

Answer (score 1):

You have calculated the rejection probability correctly. It is the probability of having all the three selected units to be defective.

Now, if you have understood the first part correctly, the probability, that you have calculated for $P(accepted)$, is the probability of having all the three selected items non-defective. However, in order to calculate $P(accepted)$, you should calculate the probability of having at least one of the three items to be non-defective. This probability is equal to $1-P(rejected)$. The hard way to calculate it, is as follows.

Let $X$ be a random variable that shows the number of defective units.

$P(accepted)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=C(85,3)+C(15,1)C(85,2)+C(85,1)C(15,2)$

Comment: I have not understood....about probability of at least one working....Because to reject the lot all three should be bad....and to accept the lot all three samples should be good.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes....thank you.....your first comment itself set me thinking...and I came to the same result